# Cross-domain javascript <-> php

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer-7

I'm having a heck of a time building a simple API using JS and PHP.  To start, I have utilized an example/solution on Script Tutorials [Javascript cross-domain api for your website](http://www.script-tutorials.com/javascript-cross-domain-api-for-your-website/).  The code works as expected on a standard browser; however, I'm stuck with IE7, in which the example doesn't work.

Any words of wisdom (other then not using Internet Exploder 7)?

Thanks in advance,
Kate

-

As per epascarello suggestion I ended up with the following (this is a very dirty test version):

CLIENT-SIDE example from [schock.net](http://schock.net/articles/2013/02/05/how-jsonp-really-works-examples/):

```
<html>
<script>
    function jsonpCallback(data){
        alert(data);
    }

    // Create a new script element
    var script_element = document.createElement('script');

    // Set its source to the JSONP API
    script_element.src = 'http://myserver.com/api.php?callback=jsonpCallback';

    // Stick the script element in the page <head>
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_element);   
</script>
</html>
```

SERVER-SIDE example from [www.geekality.net](http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/):

```
<?php 
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

function is_valid_callback($subject)
{
    $identifier_syntax = '/^[$_\p{L}][$_\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\x{200C}\x{200D}]*+$/u';

    $reserved_words = array('break', 'do', 'instanceof', 'typeof', 'case',
      'else', 'new', 'var', 'catch', 'finally', 'return', 'void', 'continue', 
      'for', 'switch', 'while', 'debugger', 'function', 'this', 'with', 
      'default', 'if', 'throw', 'delete', 'in', 'try', 'class', 'enum', 
      'extends', 'super', 'const', 'export', 'import', 'implements', 'let', 
      'private', 'public', 'yield', 'interface', 'package', 'protected', 
      'static', 'null', 'true', 'false');

    return preg_match($identifier_syntax, $subject) && !in_array(strtolower($subject), $reserved_words);

}

$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$json = json_encode($data);

# Verify JSON callback and respond
if (is_valid_callback($_GET['callback'])) 
    exit("{$_GET['callback']}($json)");

# Handle a bad request
header('status: 400 Bad Request', true, 400);

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Need something more specific than "it isn't working".

Comment: "The code works as expected on a standard browser; however, I'm stuck with IE7" --- Sounds all too familiar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you can't do what you are doing with IE7 since it does not support CORS. You would need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) if you want to support that browser.